# Real and Imaginary matrix

Tags: matrix, complex

I have a 2 by 2 matrix T: `{{x, y}, {-y, x}}` where x is the real part of some complex number and y is the imaginary part of something complex number. Let's say z1 = 1 + i2. How would I do T[z1] where x would be 1 and y would be 2?

Comment: Try `{#, Cross[#]} &@ReIm[1 + 2 I]` or `{IdentityMatrix[2], -LeviCivitaTensor[2]}.ReIm[1 + 2 I]` and report back.

Comment: `T[z_] = {{Re[z], Im[z]}, {-Im[z], Re[z]}}; z1 = 1 + 2 I; T[z1]` evaluates to `{{1, 2}, {-2, 1}}`

Answer (score 1):

The comments provide very nice answers. Perhaps you wish the 2 x 2 analogs of 1 and I:

```
r = IdentityMatrix[2];
i = {{0, -1}, {1, 0}};
fun[z_] := {r, i}.ReIm[z]
```

Note `i.i` yields `{{-1,0},{0,-1}}`= `-IdentityMatrix[2]`.

Look at the comments as they show very nice ways of achieving this.